# Intro lyrics to Janelle Monae's "Django Jane"

Tags: lyrics

On Janelle Monae's excellent new album, the track ["Django Jane"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTjQq5rMlEY) follows directly after the song "Screwed."  The lyrics from the previous song are clearly "Let's get screwed," but at the start of the new track, it transitions into:

> Let's get [unintelligible --sounds like blotto, sotto, etc]

Lyrics sites such as Genius omit the intro and only start in with Janelle's rap verse.

Is it just nonsense lyrics, or is there an actual meaning?  Perhaps not in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No official source, but from my own listening: it sounds like she's sampling her own vocals from Screwed. She starts out saying "Let's get sc-" from when she says "Let's get screwed" and then splices it with "I don't" from when she says "I don't care". And then she repeats "I don't" a few times and finally ends with "care" right before her first verse starts.

Comment: Good theory, I hadn't considered that

Comment: I wasn't convinced at first, but after listening to both songs carefully, I think you are correct. :)